# Wordpress plugin throwing 404

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a wordpress plugin which pulls data from a custom table (e.g. products)

I would like to have any URL that begins with "products" handled by the plugin so I have:

```
add_action('parse_request', 'my_url_handler');

function my_url_handler()
{
    // Manually parse the URL request
    if(!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
    {
        $urlvars = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }


    if(isset($urlvars[1]) && $urlvars[1] == 'products')
    {
        $pluginPath = dirname(__FILE__);
        require_once($pluginPath.'/templates/products.php');
    }
}
```

In $pluginPath.'/templates/products.php I have:

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>
My content
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

However, when the page is rendered WP appears to insert the 404 code (as well as products.php) and the admin menu bar isn't rendered

What I need to know:

1. How does wordpress detect a 404 - do I need to set something to tell it not to throw this?
2. Why does the admin bar not show - I see from searching this is usually due to the plugin - however not sure how to start debugging...

Any pointers would be great as running out of google links to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not going about this in the most optimal way. Wordpress has functions to account for URL rewrites. What you are doing has now way of letting Wordpress know that the request is processed and not a 404. Here is what you should be doing instead:

```
add_action( 'init', 'yourplugin_rewrite_init' );

function yourplugin_rewrite_init() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'products/([0-9]+)/?$', // I assume your product ID is numeric only, change the regex to suit.
        'index.php?pagename=products&product_id=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'yourplugin_add_query_vars' );

function yourplugin_add_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'product_id';
    return $query_vars;
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'yourplugin_rewrite_templates' );

function yourplugin_rewrite_templates() {
    if ( get_query_var( 'product_id' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'template_include', function() {
            return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/products.php';
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! - this has been so painful for me to find docs on and this just made it clear :)